# Как установить Checked в определенных позициях ListView?

Tags: java, android

Прописываю в разметке:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvHid"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
    >
</ListView>
```

В OnCreate:

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, nameChoice);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            SparseBooleanArray chosen = ((ListView) parent).getCheckedItemPositions();
            list_kit="";
            //Создаю строку с номерами включ.позиций
            for (int i = 0; i < chosen.size(); i++) {
                if (chosen.valueAt(i)) { list_kit = list_kit + chosen.keyAt(i)+";"; }
            }
        }
    });
```

А как мне установить в определенных позициях Checked = True, т.е. "проставить" галочки программно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А что так?

```
lv.setItemChecked(position, true)
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setItemChecked(int,%20boolean)

Comment: Не "прокатывает".

Comment: Должно прокатывать, главное вызывать после `lv.setAdapter(adapter)`

Comment: Да, ступил, надо было вызывать после lv.setAdapter(adapter)!!!